# Making the jQuery countdown accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a simple jQuery countdown running on a website.
I'm trying to make this widget WAI-ARIA compliant.

Requirements are as follows:

- Make the area live, so it updates with the countdown.
- Don't read the seconds, as those will be distracting to the user.
- Read in an understandable manner (ex. "59 minutes", not "59").
- Read in order (hours, then minutes).
- HTML source cannot be changed.

Below is the code for the jQuery countdown widget.

```
<div id="countdown" class="countdown">
    <div class="seconds">
        <div class="seconds-digits">07</div>
        <div class="label">seconds</div>
    </div>
    <div class="minutes">
        <div class="minutes-digits">03</div>
        <div class="label">minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hours">
        <div class="hours-digits">118</div>
        <div class="label">hours</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My initial idea was to make `.minutes` and `.hours` live and atomic. This will ensure proper reading of the updated values, as well as "minutes" and "hours" suffix. Sadly, however, this does not read them in the right order. I'm also not entirely sure it's the most correct way of doing things, since [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions#Preferring_Specialized_Live_Region_Roles) uses `role=timer` to describe a countdown.

> [timer] or any kind of timer or clock, such as a countdown timer or stopwatch readout.

The semantic purpose of the countdown is to update the user on the time left until the deadline. This could span for days (but not weeks).

This is what I've attempted:

```
// Correct position of elements
$('#countdown').append($('.seconds')).append($('.minutes'));

// Make wanted elements live
$('.minutes, .hours').attr({
    'aria-live': 'assertive',
    'aria-atomic': 'true'
});
```

But correcting the position of the elements did not change the order in which the elements are read. I think this is because the author of the webpage updated the seconds first, then the minutes and then the hours (the `.html('%S')` line comes before the `.html('%M')` line).

The output I receive from my solution is

```
03 minutes 118 hours
```

The expected output is

```
118 hours and 03 minutes to deadline
```

Comment: add whatever you did first, JS, HTML , explain whatever you want as output

Comment: Added :) My solution was in jQuery, as I cannot touch the source HTML nor the source JS.

Comment: I would just create a new element in the DOM, with the elements you want, in the order you want them read, with the aria attributes you want, and update it when the existing countdown updates at the frequency you want. Set the visibility to hidden or position it off screen.

Comment: That would be the most intuitive solution, but I want to check if there are more effective solutions out there. Adding what is essentially another countdown timer to the site doesn't seem optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the valid values of [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live) are `assertive`, `off`, and `polite`.  Setting it to `true` may have unexpected results.  Some browsers may interpret `true` as `polite`, but you'd be lucky.

Also, you are setting two different elements as live - the minutes and the hours - which means they can be updated separately and stacked on the aria-live queue in the order they change.  You should have `aria-live` on the entire countdown.  Since you don't want seconds announced, you could add `aria-hidden` to seconds so that only minutes and hours are announced. Something like this (untested):

```
// Make countdown live
$('.countdown').attr({
    'aria-live': 'polite',
    'aria-atomic': 'true'
});
// Hide seconds
$('.seconds').attr({
    'aria-hidden': 'true'
});
```

Comment: Apologies! I meant ```aria-live=assertive```. I've since corrected the post. Unfortunately, this solution will not give the desired output. A ```polite``` setting will not read the "minutes" and "hours" text, just the numbers. It will also only update the changed values, so the screen reader will only read hours when hours are changed.

Comment: Make sure you coded it correctly.  Setting `aria-atomic='true'` on the 'countdown' container means all the text, both changed and unchanged, will be read, so 'minutes' and 'hours' will be read.

Comment: I just tried it with JAWS and NVDA and it worked great.

Comment: I tested it on jsFiddle and it works, but doesn't work on the original website with the exact same HTML. Upvoted because it's a good answer. Only missing the order in which things are read (minutes come before seconds).

Comment: @AlexOsheter thanks for the upvote.  it's a tough situation since you can't change the html.  what's wrong with the order it's read?  you said "minutes before seconds", which is actually the normal order with a countdown (5 min 32 sec), but you also said you don't want seconds.  did you mean minutes is read before **hours**?  that would sound backwards (5 min 3 hrs), but it's also the order of your DOM.  does the timer actually show "07 seconds 03 minutes  118 hours" (from your original html example)?

Comment: Yeah, I meant minutes before hours. And yes, the order is backwards, this is because the original site is in Hebrew. The creator of the website made the entire website RTL (html, css and scripts etc). Subsequently, the elements in the DOM that should be read LTR are placed backwards.Visually, they're LTR, but in the DOM, they're RTL (seconds at the top).

Comment: You’ve done your best. You have a pretty accessible solution. I’d count it as a victory.